# Broken HTML tags - BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The below code perfectly scrapes the data from [this website](http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=14), except a few records which are contained in either broken HTML or are in different tags. Also, the initial letters for some of the names are not appearing, like for Cyclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd on [this page](http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=15)  How can i fix this to have all the names appearing correctly :-

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

urls = []
for i in range(14,25):
    pages = "http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID={0}".format(i)
    urls.append(pages)
for info in urls:
    entry=[]
    page = requests.get(info)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html5lib')
    text = [' '.join(items.split()) for items in soup(text =re.compile(r"Ltd$"))]
    print(text)
```

The output i am getting is

```
['ASL Shipyard Pte Ltd', 'Damen Shipyards Singapore Pte Ltd', 'DDW-PaxOcean Shipyard Pte Ltd', 'Dundee Marine & Industrial Services Pte Ltd', 'Dyna-Mac Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'Five Aluminium Boat & Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Keppel FELS Ltd', 'Keppel Offshore & Marine Ltd', 'Keppel Shipyard Ltd', 'Keppel Singmarine Pte Ltd', 'Kim Heng Marine & Oilfield Pte Ltd', 'Kim Seah Boat Builders Pte Ltd', 'Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd', 'Pandan Shipyard Pte Ltd', 'Penguin International Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Integrated Yard Pte Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Offshore Platforms Pte Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Repairs & Upgrades Pte Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Specialised Shipbuilding Pte Ltd', 'ST Engineering Marine Ltd', 'Strategic Marine (S) Pte Ltd', 'YTC Shipyard Pte Ltd']
['edge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'yclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Engie Axima Singapore Pte Ltd', '& Hopman Engineering Pte Ltd', 'OceanMaster Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Sindex Refrigeration Pte Ltd', 'Viking Engineering Pte Ltd']
[]
['Aedge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Allbest Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Atwin Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Chugoku Marine Paints (S) Pte Ltd', 'Drew Ameriod (S) Pte Ltd', 'Hempel (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Hypex Engineering & Services Pte Ltd', 'ternational Paint Singapore Pte Ltd', 'LNT Coating Pte Ltd', 'PPG Coatings (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Viking Engineering Pte Ltd']
['edge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Alphatron Marine Systems Pte Ltd', 'Codar (Pte) Ltd', 'Emerson Process Management Marine Solutions Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Furuno Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Jason Electronics (Pte) Ltd', 'Kongsberg Maritime Pte Ltd', 'Singapore Telecommunications Ltd', 'STSTC Pte Ltd', 'SWTS Pte Ltd']
['QA Systems Pte Ltd', 'Rigging & Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'Royscan Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Weldtech Inspection Services (S) Pte Ltd']
['ABB Pte Ltd', 'Aedge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Alfa Laval Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Allbest Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Alpine Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'Apbco Offshore & Marine Pte Ltd', 'Atwin Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Brightsun Marine Pte Ltd', 'Candid Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Crestchic (Asia-Pacific) Pte Ltd', 'Cutech Solutions & Services Pte Ltd', 'Cyclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Devcon Enterprises Pte Ltd', 'yna-Mac Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'EELAT Pte Ltd', 'Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Eng Soon Investment Pte Ltd', 'Five Aluminium Boat & Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Foo Ngan Marine Pte Ltd', 'Foster Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'obal Offshore & Marine Pte Ltd', 'Goltens Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Great Sun Offshore Pte Ltd', 'Heatec JieTong Pte Ltd', 'HongRong Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Hoo Huat Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Hup Hoe Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Hypex Engineering & Services Pte Ltd', 'Index-Cool Marine & Industry Pte Ltd', 'Jemix Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Johnson Controls (S) Pte Ltd', 'Keppel Sea Scan Pte Ltd', 'Kim Heng Marine & Oilfield Pte Ltd', 'Kim Seah Boat Builders Pte Ltd', 'Kok & Chan Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'K S Automation Pte Ltd', 'Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd', 'Lam Heng Marine Pte Ltd', 'LPJ Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'Major Engineering and Technology Pte Ltd', 'Mantech Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Maritime Associates Pte Ltd', 'Mectrade Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Megawatts Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'Mencast Holdings Ltd', 'Mentrade Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'New & Novel Engineering Pte Ltd', 'OceanMaster Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Onda Industries Engineering Marine Pte Ltd', 'QA Systems Pte Ltd', 'Rolls-Royce Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Royscan Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Seagull Pte Ltd', 'Seah Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'SeaTech Solutions International (S) Pte Ltd', 'Sentek Marine & Trading Pte Ltd', 'Siong Leng Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Sparrows Offshore Services (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'SPCO Holdings Pte Ltd', 'Straits Innovation Pte Ltd', 'Star-Ray Pte Ltd', 'Ta-Ching Marine Technology Pte Ltd', 'Tech-Growth Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Tech Offshore Marine (S) Pte Ltd', 'Tru-Marine Pte Ltd', 'Viking Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Vita Enterprises Pte Ltd', 'Vosper Naval Systems Pte Ltd', 'Wah Soon Marine Pte Ltd', 'Yanmar Asia (S) Corporation Pte Ltd', 'Yong Cheong Marine & Engineering Pte Ltd']
['Caterpillar Marine Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Chong Lee Leong Seng Co Ltd', 'Cinta Asia (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Cummins Sales and Service Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Daikai Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Harris Pye Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Junma Services Pte Ltd', 'Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd', 'MAN Energy Solutions Singapore Pte Ltd', 'MTU Asia Pte Ltd', 'Power Diesel Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Rolls-Royce Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Stewart Engineering Works (S) Pte Ltd', 'Tractors Singapore Ltd', 'Tru-Marine Pte Ltd', 'Wartsila Singapore Pte Ltd', 'West Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Xin Ming Hua Pte Ltd', 'Yanmar Asia (S) Corporation Pte Ltd']
['ABB Pte Ltd', 'Pte Ltd', 'Atlas Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'eng Hui Marine Electrical Pte Ltd', 'Best Technology Pte Ltd', 'hong Lee Leong Seng Co Ltd', 'Cinta Asia (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Daikai Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Drew Ameriod (S) Pte Ltd', 'Emerson Process Management Marine Solutions Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Engtek Pte Ltd', 'ERIKS Pte Ltd', 'ESAB Asia/Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Excel Marco Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Fassmer Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Finetek Pte Ltd', 'Flotech Controls Pte Ltd', 'Franklin Offshore International Pte Ltd', 'Global Marine Safety (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Griffin Group International Pte Ltd', 'Griffin Kinetic Pte Ltd', 'Harris Pye Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Hup Hoe Engineering Pte Ltd', 'HydroPro Pte Ltd', 'ICF International Pte Ltd', 'Industmarine Engineers Pte Ltd', 'Invertek Drives Far East Pte Ltd', 'Kelvin Hughes (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Keppel Sea Scan Pte Ltd', 'Kheng Cheong Co Pte Ltd', 'KM Kinley Marketing Pte Ltd', 'Kongsberg Maritime Pte Ltd', 'Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd', 'acGregor Pte Ltd', 'Marinelec Technologies Asia Pte Ltd', 'Mencast Subsea Pte Ltd', 'MTU Asia Pte Ltd', 'Niigata Power Systems (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Nordic Flow Control Pte Ltd', 'OceanMaster Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Omega Pro Tech (1996) Pte Ltd', 'lfinger Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Pamarine Pte Ltd', 'PH Hydraulics & Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Poclain Hydraulics Pte Ltd', 'K Instruments (S) Pte Ltd', 'Rapid Marine HVAC (Asia-Pacific) Pte Ltd', 'Reintjes Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Robert Bosch (South East Asia) Pte Ltd', 'Scanjet Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Scanvik Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'Schottel Far East (Pte) Ltd', 'Seaquest Enterprise Pte Ltd', 'Seng Heng Engineering Pte Ltd', 'SES Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'Singapore Cables Manufacturers Pte Ltd', 'SL Metals Pte Ltd', 'Sparrows Offshore Services (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Springer-EMS Pte Ltd', 'Teho International Inc Ltd', 'Tractors Singapore Ltd', 'Trans-Asiatic Trading Pte Ltd', 'Transvictory Winch System Pte Ltd', 'Turbo Solutions Pte Ltd', 'alves & Piping Asia Pte Ltd', 'Viking Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Wartsila Pumps Pte Ltd', 'Xin Ming Hua Pte Ltd', 'Z-Power Automation Pte Ltd', 'ZF Asia Pacific Pte Ltd']
['Aedge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Any Mari Scaffolding Pte Ltd', 'HHE Scaffold Pte Ltd', 'Hoo Huat Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Multiheight Scaffolding Pte Ltd', 'Singa Marine Scaffolding Pte Ltd']
['Aedge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Apbco Offshore & Marine Pte Ltd', 'ASL Solutions Pte Ltd', 'Astoria Solutions Pte Ltd', 'CESCO Environmental Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Cutech Solutions & Services Pte Ltd', 'Ecospec Global Technology Pte Ltd', 'Global Fire Solution Pte Ltd', 'Griffin Kinetic Pte Ltd', 'Kim Heng Marine & Oilfield Pte Ltd', 'M3 Marine Group Pte Ltd', 'Maritime Associates Pte Ltd', 'NSL OilChem Waste Management Pte Ltd', 'NYK ShipManagement Pte Ltd', 'ower Systech Pte Ltd', 'Rubicon Offshore International Pte Ltd', 'Seaquest Enterprise Pte Ltd', 'Sentek Marine & Trading Pte Ltd', 'The National Forwarder (S) Pte Ltd', 'Vision Global Engineering & Safety Services Pte Ltd']
```

Any input would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: Hi renu, i think that I've solved that issue for you before ?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, no it was another one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404674/beautifulsoup-not-fetching-the-data

Comment: so you want to take the `SHIPYARDS` company names for all pages?

Comment: The names for all companies are coming for all pages in the loop, except for some as i mentioned in the question

Comment: and for some records the initial alphabets are missing , but i am seeking to get all names with complete names for all the mentioned pages

Comment: that site is very interesting. let me see workaround

Comment: Sure !! Thank you so much for taking out time for this,

Comment: you welcome, Issue is fixed. check my answer below

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204713/discussion-between--c-and-renu).

Comment: i tried your suggestion and through your approach i could get the Zipcode, email, website, contact person , but couldn't extract the names properly & Address also, as i couldn't figure out the correct REGEX for Address line, Can you please help me on that

Comment: you should open a new question for that as it’s different approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


for num in range(14, 25):
    r = requests.get(f"http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID={num}")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    names = list(dict.fromkeys([' '.join(items.split())
                                for items in soup(text=re.compile(r'Ltd\s?$'))]))
    print(names)
```

Your assumption is wrong that each name ends with `Ltd`.

If you look at the source for [page#14](http://www.asmi.com/index.cfm?GPID=14)

You actually were missing 2 company names and sure for other pages as well:

```
Crestsa Marine & Offshore Pte Ltd 
MMA Offshore Shipyard and Engineering Services Pte Ltd
```

If you did look at the source for the first company:

`<a name="C"></a>Crestsa Marine &amp; Offshore Pte Ltd&nbsp;<br />`

`&nbsp;` is non-breakable space `ASCII 160`

Thus the `Ltd$` regex will not match, Because you have `Ltd\xa0` at the end

So with `r'Ltd\s?$'` is now fixed.

Output:

```
['ASL Shipyard Pte Ltd', 'Crestsa Marine & Offshore Pte Ltd', 'Damen Shipyards Singapore Pte Ltd', 'DDW-PaxOcean Shipyard Pte Ltd', 'Dundee Marine & Industrial Services Pte Ltd', 'Dyna-Mac Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'Five Aluminium Boat & Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Keppel FELS Ltd', 'Keppel Offshore & Marine Ltd', 'Keppel Shipyard Ltd', 'Keppel Singmarine Pte Ltd', 'Kim Heng Marine & Oilfield Pte Ltd', 'Kim Seah Boat Builders Pte Ltd', 'Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd', 'MA Offshore Shipyard and Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'Pandan Shipyard Pte Ltd', 'Penguin International Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Integrated Yard Pte Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Offshore Platforms Pte Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Repairs & Upgrades Pte Ltd', 'Sembcorp Marine Specialised Shipbuilding Pte Ltd', 'ST Engineering Marine Ltd', 'Strategic Marine (S) Pte Ltd', 'YTC Shipyard Pte Ltd']
['edge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'yclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Engie Axima 
Singapore Pte Ltd', '& Hopman Engineering Pte Ltd', 'OceanMaster Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Sindex Refrigeration Pte Ltd', 'Viking Engineering Pte Ltd']
['Marine (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Singapore Pte Ltd', 'RINA Hong Kong Ltd']
['Aedge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Allbest Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Atwin Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Chugoku Marine Paints (S) Pte Ltd', 'Drew Ameriod (S) Pte Ltd', 'Hempel (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Hypex Engineering & Services Pte Ltd', 'ternational Paint Singapore Pte Ltd', 'LNT Coating Pte Ltd', 'PPG Coatings (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Viking Engineering Pte Ltd']
['edge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Alphatron Marine Systems Pte Ltd', 'Codar (Pte) Ltd', 'Emerson Process Management Marine Solutions Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Furuno Singapore 
Pte Ltd', 'Jason Electronics (Pte) Ltd', 'Kongsberg Maritime Pte Ltd', 'Masstron Pte Ltd', 'Modern Automation & Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Singapore Telecommunications Ltd', 'STSTC Pte Ltd', 'SWTS Pte Ltd']
['QA Systems Pte Ltd', 'Rigging & Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'Royscan Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Weldtech Inspection Services (S) Pte Ltd']
['ABB Pte Ltd', 'Aedge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Alfa Laval Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Allbest Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Alpine Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'Apbco Offshore & Marine Pte Ltd', 'Arc Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Atwin Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Brightsun Marine Pte Ltd', 'Candid Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Crestchic 
(Asia-Pacific) Pte Ltd', 'Cutech Solutions & Services Pte Ltd', 'Cyclect Electrical 
Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Devcon Enterprises Pte Ltd', 'yna-Mac Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'EELAT Pte Ltd', 'Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Eng Soon Investment Pte Ltd', 'Five Aluminium Boat & Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Foo Ngan Marine Pte Ltd', 'Foster Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'obal Offshore & Marine Pte Ltd', 'Goltens Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Great Sun Offshore Pte Ltd', 'Harris Pye Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Heatec JieTong Pte Ltd', 'HongRong Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Hoo Huat Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Hup Hoe Engineering Pte 
Ltd', 'Hypex Engineering & Services Pte Ltd', 'Index-Cool Marine & Industry Pte Ltd', 'Japan Marine United Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Jemix Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Johnson Controls (S) Pte Ltd', 'Keppel Sea Scan Pte Ltd', 'Kim Heng Marine & Oilfield Pte Ltd', 'Kim Seah Boat Builders Pte Ltd', 'Kok & Chan Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'K S Automation Pte Ltd', 'Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd', 'Lal Offshore Marine Pte Ltd', 'Lam Heng Marine Pte Ltd', 'LPJ Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'Major Engineering and Technology Pte Ltd', 'Mantech Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Maritime Associates Pte Ltd', 'Mectrade Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Megawatts Engineering Services Pte Ltd', 'Mencast Holdings Ltd', 'Mentrade Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'MR Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 
'MTQ Engineering Pte Ltd', 'New & Novel Engineering Pte Ltd', 'OceanMaster Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Onda Industries Engineering Marine Pte Ltd', 'Promor Pte Ltd', 'QA Systems Pte Ltd', 'Rolls-Royce Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Royscan Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Seagull Pte Ltd', 'Seah Marine Engineering Pte Ltd', 'SeaTech Solutions International (S) Pte Ltd', 'Sentek Marine & Trading Pte Ltd', 'Siemens Pte Ltd', 'Siong Leng Engineering Pte Ltd', 'SMIT Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Sparrows Offshore Services (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'SPCO Holdings Pte Ltd', 'Straits Innovation Pte Ltd', 'Star-Ray Pte Ltd', 'SWTS Pte Ltd', 'Ta-Ching Marine Technology Pte Ltd', 'Tech-Growth Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Tech Offshore Marine (S) Pte Ltd', 'Tru-Marine Pte Ltd', 'Viking Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Vita Enterprises Pte Ltd', 'Vosper Naval Systems Pte Ltd', 'Wah Soon Marine Pte Ltd', 'Welmet Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Yanmar Asia (S) Corporation Pte Ltd', 'Yong Cheong Marine & Engineering Pte Ltd']
['Caterpillar Marine Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Chong Lee Leong Seng Co Ltd', 'Cinta Asia (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Cummins Sales and Service Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Daikai Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Harris Pye Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Japan Marine United Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Junma Services Pte Ltd', 'Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd', 'MAN Energy Solutions Singapore Pte Ltd', 'MTU Asia Pte Ltd', 'Power Diesel Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Rolls-Royce Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Stewart Engineering Works (S) Pte Ltd', 'Tractors Singapore Ltd', 'Tru-Marine Pte Ltd', 'Wartsila Singapore Pte Ltd', 'West Marine 
Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Xin Ming Hua Pte Ltd', 'Yanmar Asia (S) Corporation Pte Ltd']
['ABB Pte Ltd', 'Aflex Ships Equipment Pte Ltd', 'Pte Ltd', 'Atlas Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'eng Hui Marine Electrical Pte Ltd', 'Best Technology Pte Ltd', 'Bloomfoss 
Pte Ltd', 'hong Lee Leong Seng Co Ltd', 'Cinta Asia (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Crestsa Marine & Offshore Pte Ltd', 'Daikai Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Drew Ameriod (S) Pte Ltd', 'Emerson Process Management Marine Solutions Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Engtek Pte Ltd', 
'ERIKS Pte Ltd', 'ESAB Asia/Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Excel Marco Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Fassmer Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Finetek Pte Ltd', 'Flotech Controls Pte Ltd', 'Franklin Offshore International Pte Ltd', 'Gardyon Pte Ltd', 'Global Marine Safety (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Griffin Group International Pte Ltd', 'Griffin Kinetic Pte Ltd', 'Harris Pye Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Hup Hoe Engineering Pte Ltd', 'HydroPro Pte Ltd', 'ICF International Pte Ltd', 'Industmarine Engineers Pte Ltd', 'Invertek Drives Far East Pte Ltd', 'Japan Marine United Singapore Pte Ltd', 'Kelvin Hughes (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Keppel Sea Scan Pte Ltd', 'Kheng Cheong Co Pte Ltd', 'KM Kinley Marketing Pte Ltd', 
'Kongsberg Maritime Pte Ltd', 'KTL Offshore Pte Ltd', 'Kwong Soon Engineering Co. (Pte) Ltd', 'acGregor Pte Ltd', 'Marinelec Technologies Asia Pte Ltd', 'Mencast Subsea Pte Ltd', 'MEP Deck Solutions Pte Ltd', 'Mooreast Asia Pte Ltd', 'MTU Asia Pte Ltd', 'Niigata Power Systems (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Nordic Flow Control Pte Ltd', 'OceanMaster Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Omega Pro Tech (1996) Pte Ltd', 'lfinger Asia Pacific 
Pte Ltd', 'Pamarine Pte Ltd', 'PH Hydraulics & Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Poclain Hydraulics Pte Ltd', 'K Instruments (S) Pte Ltd', 'Rapid Marine HVAC (Asia-Pacific) Pte Ltd', 'Reintjes Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Robert Bosch (South East Asia) Pte Ltd', 'Scanjet Asia Pacific Pte Ltd', 'Scanvik Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'Schottel Far East (Pte) Ltd', 'Seaquest Enterprise Pte Ltd', 'Seng Heng Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Sensitron 
Singapore (Sensing) Pte Ltd', 'SES Marine Services Pte Ltd', 'Singapore Cables Manufacturers Pte Ltd', 'SL Metals Pte Ltd', 'Sparrows Offshore Services (Singapore) Pte 
Ltd', 'Springer-EMS Pte Ltd', 'Tat Wai Enterprise Pte Ltd', 'Teho International Inc 
Ltd', 'Tractors Singapore Ltd', 'Trans-Asiatic Trading Pte Ltd', 'Transvictory Winch System Pte Ltd', 'Tri-Star Industries Pte Ltd', 'Turbo Solutions Pte Ltd', 'Uniclimb Services Pte Ltd', 'alves & Piping Asia Pte Ltd', 'Viking Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Wartsila Pumps Pte Ltd', 'Xin Ming Hua Pte Ltd', 'Z-Power Automation Pte Ltd', 'ZF Asia Pacific Pte Ltd']
['Aedge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Any Mari Scaffolding Pte Ltd', 'HHE Scaffold Pte Ltd', 'Hoo Huat Engineering Pte Ltd', 'Multiheight Scaffolding Pte Ltd', 'Singa Marine 
Scaffolding Pte Ltd']
['Aedge Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Apbco Offshore & Marine Pte Ltd', 'ASL Solutions Pte Ltd', 'Astoria Solutions Pte Ltd', 'CESCO Environmental Technologies Pte Ltd', 'Crestsa Marine & Offshore Pte Ltd', 'Cutech Solutions & Services Pte Ltd', 'Ecospec Global Technology Pte Ltd', 'Global Fire Solution Pte Ltd', 'Griffin Kinetic Pte Ltd', 
'Kim Heng Marine & Oilfield Pte Ltd', 'M3 Marine Group Pte Ltd', 'Maritime Associates Pte Ltd', 'Mosestide Pte Ltd', 'NSL OilChem Waste Management Pte Ltd', 'NYK ShipManagement Pte Ltd', 'ower Systech Pte Ltd', 'Rubicon Offshore International Pte Ltd', 'Seaquest Enterprise Pte Ltd', 'Sentek Marine & Trading Pte Ltd', 'Sinwa (Singapore) Pte Ltd', 'Six Tee Engineering Groups Pte Ltd', 'The National Forwarder (S) Pte Ltd', 'Vision Global Engineering & Safety Services Pte Ltd']
```

Regarding your question about the name of `Cyclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd`

Actually the source include the following for it

`yclect Electrical Engineering Pte Ltd`

And regarding the letter `C` it's inside the following:

```
<span style="font-size: small;">
<strong>C</strong>
```

I've noticed that you only taken the companies which ending with `Ltd` but there's others as well. i do believe that you tried with that but actually the website is completely crab !

but you can use something like that to get the missed.

```py
    other = list(dict.fromkeys([items.text
                                for items in soup.findAll("strong", text=True)]))
    print(names+other)
```